# Spring MVC Base Controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have method which logically should be in base controller class (uploading icons) for different controllers. That is not a functionality of specific controller. Here is the code:

```
public abstract class BaseTabsManagementController{
    ...
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/upload_tab_icon")
    public @ResponseBody Response<List<Icon>> saveIcon(@RequestParam("tabIcon") MultipartFile file,
            @ModelAttribute(TAB_BEAN) AddEditTabBean tabBean) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have 2 derived controllers `AddEditTabController` and `AddEditContentPageController`. But when I'm running the code I'm getting the following exception

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler 'addEditTabController' to URL path [/admin/ui/upload_tab_icon]: There is already handler of type [class com.synisys.idm.analytics.designer.controller.AddEditContentPageController] mapped.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
.......
```

Has anybody idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Why does it need to be in a base class? Why not in its own controller?  The way you are doing it now leads to multiple handlers on the same URL (if you don't have an additional `@RequestMapping` on the class level.)

Comment: @M. Deinum Well may be I can define IconUploadController, but logically those icons are uploading for those objects, therefore I have defined this way. I was thought that there should be a way to config Spring on this method level to recognize it once. Is that possible?)

Comment: No. You have multiple classes and as such multiple methods. If they are different they should have different urls. Hence my hint on the class level `@RequestMapping` for the concrete implementation classes.

Comment: Well, will note this, but still waiting for interesting solutions :)

Comment: @ArsenAlexanyan Are you planning to upload different icons for each controller, or is there only one kind of icon?

Comment: @geoand That's not matter can be uploaded different icons for both controllers

Comment: @ArsenAlexanyan I am asking because if you only need one type of icon you should use a dedicated controller like M.Deinum mentions. If you are going to need different icons for each controller, then you have gone down the right path, but it's just a Spring configuration issue that can be fixed

Comment: @ geoand The uploaded set is the same for both controllers but the icon type as You mentioned can be different, I have not filters on icon types.